# Android camera : Where are face tags stored?

Tags: android, android-camera

The camera of my Samsung galaxy S5 detects faces automatically and asks for names. 
Are these tags stored in the devices or sent over the network (to samsung or google)? If on the device where are they stored, in order to avoid losing them when I copy pictures to my PC.

**Edit :** I am still looking for the answer.. is there any way to monitor where my phone writes data when he is doing it (like filemon and regmon for PC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the Face Detection API from the Android SDK.

Please refer the Documentation - [android.media.FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html)

> Method [findFaces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html#findFaces%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.media.FaceDetector.Face%5B%5D%29): Finds all the faces found in a given Bitmap.

Comment: [This link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/10/28/implementing-face-detection-in-android) also provides good information

Comment: That means the camera app uses the android facedetetion API, and than stores the information somewhere.. I need to know where this somewhere is (to keep it, because it doesn't make sense to tag all pictures in the mobile and loose it all after a phone formatting or when I change the device)